# Bad bind variable PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, trigger

Tengo este código, y me muestra el mensaje de error:

> bid band variable

```
Trigger TRG_PAISES_EUROPA compilado

LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
5/113     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.CONTINENTE'
7/73      PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.HABITANTES'
Errores: comprobar log de compilador
```

Las columnas de la tabla son correctas.

Código:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_PAISES_EUROPA
    INSTEAD OF INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON paises_europa_vista
        DECLARE
        v_ciudadMasPoblada PAISES_EUROPA_VISTA.ciudadmaspoblada%TYPE;
        BEGIN
            IF INSERTING THEN 
                INSERT INTO PAIS(COD_PAIS,NOMBRE,CAPITAL,CONTINENTE) VALUES (:NEW.COD_PAIS,:NEW.NOMBRE,:NEW.CAPITAL,:NEW.CONTINENTE);
                    SELECT CIUDADMASPOBLADA INTO v_ciudadMasPoblada FROM PAISES_EUROPA_VISTA WHERE COD_PAIS = :NEW.COD_PAIS;
                INSERT INTO CIUDAD VALUES (:new.cod_pais,v_ciudadMasPoblada,:new.habitantes);
            ElSIF DELETING THEN
                DELETE CIUDAD WHERE COD_PAIS = :OLD.COD_PAIS;
                DELETE PAIS WHERE COD_PAIS = :OLD.COD_PAIS;
            END IF;
        END;
```

Concordando la vista es la siguiente:

Vista:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW paises_europa_vista AS 
SELECT cod_pais, nombre, capital, num_hab/extension densidad,  
 (SELECT nombre FROM ciudad  WHERE cod_pais=pais.cod_pais  AND habitantes=(SELECT MAX(habitantes)  FROM ciudad 
 WHERE cod_pais=pais.cod_pais)) ciudadmaspoblada,  
(SELECT habitantes FROM ciudad  WHERE cod_pais=pais.cod_pais  AND habitantes=(SELECT MAX(habitantes) FROM ciudad WHERE cod_pais=pais.cod_pais)) habciudadmaspoblada 
FROM pais WHERE continente='Europa' ORDER BY densidad DESC WITH CHECK OPTION;
```

Espero vuestra ayuda, muchas gracias.

Comment: Muestra la estructura de la tabla `paises_europa_vista` pulsando en [edit].

Comment: La tienes, disculpa la demora

Comment: Listo,resuelto!

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Pues, si te ayudaron, podrías compartir la solución como respuesta para que otros sepan cuál fue. Abajo en el campo de respuesta. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio Como esto no es un foro, no se edita el título para indicar cierre.

Comment: Listo, gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Tras investigar, me doy cuenta de que la vista paises_europa_vista, no tiene una columna llamada 'habitantes'. La columna se llamaba 'habciudadmaspoblada'.

Con lo cuál la solución es esta:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_PAISES_EUROPA
INSTEAD OF INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON paises_europa_vista
    DECLARE
    v_ciudadMasPoblada PAISES_EUROPA_VISTA.ciudadmaspoblada%TYPE;
    BEGIN
        IF INSERTING OR UPDATING THEN 
            INSERT INTO PAIS(COD_PAIS,NOMBRE,CAPITAL,CONTINENTE) VALUES (:NEW.COD_PAIS,:NEW.NOMBRE,:NEW.CAPITAL,'EUROPA');
                SELECT CIUDADMASPOBLADA INTO v_ciudadMasPoblada FROM PAISES_EUROPA_VISTA WHERE COD_PAIS = :NEW.COD_PAIS;
```

LÍNEA ANTIGUA:

```
   INSERT INTO CIUDAD VALUES (:new.cod_pais,v_ciudadMasPoblada,:new.habitantes);
```

LÍNEA CORREGIDA:

```
INSERT INTO CIUDAD VALUES (:new.cod_pais,v_ciudadMasPoblada,:new.habciudadmaspoblada);

        ElSIF DELETING THEN
            DELETE CIUDAD WHERE COD_PAIS = :OLD.COD_PAIS;
            DELETE PAIS WHERE COD_PAIS = :OLD.COD_PAIS;
        END IF;
        END;
```